# About rune/neutral creep/roshan spawn time

Tags: dota-2

How long does it take to spawn a rune/any neutral creeps/roshan?
Does the spawn timer start after a rune has been taken/any neutral creeps have been slained/roshan has been slained or immediately after their previous spawn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Runes

At 00h:00m:00s 2 bounty runes spawns at each spots, then, every 2 minutes, 2 new runes will spawn. One is always a bounty rune and the other a power buff (haste, double damage, regeneration, arcane, invisiblity, illusion). The location is always random and they always replace the previous rune, taken or not. 2 "power" runes in a row can not be the same.

### Neutrals

Neutrals first spawn is 30 sec after game starts (00h:00m:30s). Then, any camp will refill (every minute : min 1, min 2, min 3 etc.) with new neutrals if the camp is empty. Based on that principle you can stack camp by pulling them away from their spawn location at about 52-55 sec (Thus emptying the camp) and have one more group of neutrals spawning in the camp.

### Roshan

Roshan spawns when the game starts (even before first creeps wave). Once he's killed, there is a random timer between 8 and 11 min. At the end of the timer, Roshan respawns.

Comment: Spectators can see when roshan will respawn exactly - if they can read the respawn timer. Furthermore wards can block any spawn (except rosh)